# Объединение метода в дженерик

Tags: c#, generics, методы

У меня есть несколько похожих методов вида:

```
void MethodA_N<T>(string s) where T : RightHandSide, new()
    {
        label11.Text = s;
        backgroundWorker1 = null;
        backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        TimeLayer ts = new TimeShiftN<T>(gp, radioButton6.Checked, radioButton7.Checked, radioButton10.Checked);
        BackgroundWorkerSetup bws = new BackgroundWorkerSetup(ts.TimeScheme, backgroundWorker1);
        ts.AddBWS(bws);
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        chart3.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        chart4.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += bws.Compute;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += ts.Complete;
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += ts.ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

RightHandSide и TimeLayer - абстрактные классы для различных методов сдвига по пространству и времени соответственно. Мне бы хотелось объединить это в один вид с параметрами U, T производным от U, и V, производным от TimeLayer.

Однако у меня возникает проблема с new TimeShiftN - как мне учесть то, что мне нужно подставить в произвольный V от TimeLayer шаблон из T

**UPDATE 9:47** Мне бы хотелось вызывать метод с тремя параметрами: `MethodA_N<RightHandSide,ConcreteRightHandSide, TimeShiftN>("")`, где `RightHandSide` принимает значения из двух возможных абстрактных классов, `ConcreteRightHandSide` - наследник `RightHandSide` и отдельно `TimeShiftN`. `TimeLayer` - у меня абстрактный класс, а `TimeShiftN` - конкретный наследник абстрактного класса. Проблема в том, что `TimeShiftN` зависит от ConcreteRightHandSide

Comment: Хорошо что добавили пример вызова с тремя аргументами. Можете еще добавить что должно быть присвоено `ts` внутри метода при таком вызове?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял Вы хотите обращаться к методу так:

```
.MethodA_N<RightHandSide,TimeShiftN>("");
```

Боюсь сделать это так просто невозможно, т.к. метод содержит обращение к конструктору `TimeShiftN`, которого у других наследников `TimeLayer` может и не быть:

```
//неясно как будут создаваться другие наследники TimeLayer
TimeLayer ts = new TimeShiftN<T>(gp, radioButton6.Checked, radioButton7.Checked, radioButton10.Checked);
```

Можно вместо вызова конструктора передавать в метод функцию для создания `TimeLayer`:

```
void MethodA_N<T,U>(string s, Func<GP,bool,bool,bool,U> layerGenerator) 
    where T : RightHandSide, new()
    where U: TimeLayer
{
    ...
    TimeLayer ts = layerGenerator(gp, radioButton6.Checked, radioButton7.Checked, radioButton10.Checked);
```

Но, учитывая что `<T>` в таком методе не используется вообще, а сама функция используется только один раз, я предпочел бы принимать `TimeLayer` как аргумент и вынести инициализацию за пределы метода:

```
void MethodA_N(string s, TimeLayer ts) 
{
    ...
    BackgroundWorkerSetup bws = new BackgroundWorkerSetup(ts.TimeScheme, backgroundWorker1);
    ts.AddBWS(bws);
    ...
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
TimeLayer ts = new TimeShiftN<RightHandSide>(gp, radioButton6.Checked, radioButton7.Checked, radioButton10.Checked);
obj.MethodA_N("", ts);
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не совсем то, что я хотел.

Я хотел обращаться с тремя параметрами: MethodA_N<RightHandSide,ConcreteRightHandSide, TimeShiftN>(""), где RightHandSide принимает значения из двух возможных абстрактных классов, ConcreteRightHandSide - наследник RightHandSide и отдельно TimeShiftN.

TimeLayer - у меня абстрактный класс, а TimeShiftN - конкретный наследник абстрактного класса.

Проблема в том, что TimeShiftN зависит от ConcreteRightHandSide

Comment: @ТимофейЛомоносов А зачем передавать одновременно `RightHandSide` и `ConcreteRightHandSide`? Проблема с методом, в том что обощенные типы используются только в одной строке, которая инициализирует необобщенный тип (`TimeLayer`). Эту строку можно заменить на вызов делегата, но тогда все аргументы также перейдут в делегат.

Comment: У меня в качестве RightHandSide могут выступать абстрактные классы RHS или RelaxRHS. Соответственно, в одном случае параметр обобщённого типа для TimeShiftN<T> должен наследоваться либо от RHS, либо от RelaxRHS.

Comment: @ТимофейЛомоносов Много нового открывается за кулисами :) Все-таки приведите в вопросе для примера: а) два разных вызова метода б) чем должно отличать поведение метода при разных вызовах.

Comment: С Вашим ответом уже разобрался. Действительно проще инициализацию вынести за кулисы. И всё работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @ТимофейЛомоносов Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло. Если все-таки остались еще сомнения, то обновите вопрос и снимите галочку: возможно стоит подробнее рассмотреть альтернативы.